# how to identity if the image is upside down in c# asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, c#-4.0

if i upload an upside down image on my website it will display as it is .whereas Google chrome rotate its orientation as i want but in IE image shows as it was uploaded.how can we identify the image orientation in .Net.i.e image is upside down or not.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6222053/3913686

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Orientation parameter of the EXIF-data.
There are 8 possible values:

```
EXIF Orientation Value    Row #0 is:     Column #0 is:
1                         Top            Left side
2                         Top            Right side
3                         Bottom         Right side
4                         Bottom         Left side
5                         Left side      Top
6                         Right side     Top
7                         Right side     Bottom
8                         Left side      Bottom
```

http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

To read EXIF-data, check the solution by Nihilogic:
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/

Simpler example which seem to use the same solution:
http://blog.rrikesh.com/demo/jquery-exif.html