# Unwanted rotation when saving an image .net

Tags: .net, image, rotation

I am trying to save an image here but its getting rotated when its saved. The current code for this is like this :

`filepath` is the path to a a vertical image (width < height)

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(filePath))
                {
                    img.Save(savePath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

            }
```

After the code is run, when I check the new image that is saved, it is rotated 90 degree counterclockwise. I am unable to understand this behaviour

Suggestions and guidance on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

Comment: At a guess your original file is a JPEG that contains an EXIF tag to rotate it to the proper orientation. I suspect the .NET library is ignoring this tag.

Comment: Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation).