# Image is rotated after Resizing

Tags: c#, resize, crop

I have below code in order to resize images to proper dimensions(600,600)
it works fine, but for some images (720*1280) like this, the result is rotated (90 deg)
how can I know which images would rotate? and how Can I prevent this ?

**StackOverflow Roates the image too**

[image]

```
     public static System.Drawing.Image FixedSize(Image image, int Width,   int Height, bool needToFill)
    {
        #region calculations
        int sourceWidth = image.Width;
        int sourceHeight = image.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        double destX = 0;
        double destY = 0;

        double nScale = 0;
        double nScaleW = 0;
        double nScaleH = 0;

        nScaleW = ((double)Width / (double)sourceWidth);
        nScaleH = ((double)Height / (double)sourceHeight);
        if (!needToFill)
        {
            nScale = Math.Min(nScaleH, nScaleW);
        }
        else
        {
            nScale = Math.Max(nScaleH, nScaleW);
            destY = (Height - sourceHeight * nScale) / 2;
            destX = (Width - sourceWidth * nScale) / 2;
        }

        if (nScale > 1)
            nScale = 1;

        int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nScale);
        int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * nScale);
        #endregion

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmPhoto = null;
        try
        {
            bmPhoto = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(destWidth + (int)Math.Round(2 * destX), destHeight + (int)Math.Round(2 * destY));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("destWidth:{0}, destX:{1}, destHeight:{2}, desxtY:{3}, Width:{4}, Height:{5}",
                destWidth, destX, destHeight, destY, Width, Height), ex);
        }
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics grPhoto = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto))
        {
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            grPhoto.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            grPhoto.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            Rectangle to =  new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)Math.Round(destX), (int)Math.Round(destY), destWidth, destHeight);
            Rectangle from = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
            //Console.WriteLine("From: " + from.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine("To: " + to.ToString());
            grPhoto.DrawImage(image, to, from, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            return bmPhoto;
        }
    }
```

At first I want to prevent this, if this is not possible I want to re-rotate image to real shape

Comment: copy the exeif rotation info from your source image

Comment: The information is in the original image - have a look at https://www.howtogeek.com/254830/why-your-photos-dont-always-appear-correctly-rotated/

Comment: @fubo you mean this ?`image.PropertyItems`

Comment: here is a implemetation of the reading of orientation information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation

Comment: @fubo I add that code to my code but after resizing I debugged it and it does not contain this property `exifOrientationID`

Comment: that's the reason why your image has the wrong rotation. So you have to copy the orientation property or you have to rotate your image depending on sources orientation property

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. To solve it I had to rotate the image according to the exeif rotation info has suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33313625/4962985). But in my case I had to rotate the original image before it is resized as done [here](https://forums.asp.net/post/5802781.aspx).

```
private const int OrientationKey = 0x0112;
    private const int NotSpecified = 0;
    private const int NormalOrientation = 1;
    private const int MirrorHorizontal = 2;
    private const int UpsideDown = 3;
    private const int MirrorVertical = 4;
    private const int MirrorHorizontalAndRotateRight = 5;
    private const int RotateLeft = 6;
    private const int MirorHorizontalAndRotateLeft = 7;
    private const int RotateRight = 8;

public static Image FixedSize(Image image, ...)
    {
        // Fix orientation if needed. It appears the code isn't compensating for exif data for the image.
        // So if a photo was taken with the camera sideways, the image was displaying sideways,
        // while the computer was reading that exif data and automatically rotating it in windows to display it as it's suppose to be.
        // This code reads the exif data and rotates accordingly.
        if (image.PropertyIdList.Contains(OrientationKey))
        {
            var orientation = (int)image.GetPropertyItem(OrientationKey).Value[0];
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case NotSpecified: // Assume it is good.
                case NormalOrientation:
                    // No rotation required.
                    break;
                case MirrorHorizontal:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
                    break;
                case UpsideDown:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                    break;
                case MirrorVertical:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
                    break;
                case MirrorHorizontalAndRotateRight:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);
                    break;
                case RotateLeft:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                    break;
                case MirorHorizontalAndRotateLeft:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX);
                    break;
                case RotateRight:
                    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("An orientation of " + orientation + " isn't implemented.");
            }
        }

        // resize image code ...
        
        return bmPhoto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. I think the error occurs in your image file type extension. When I rename the abc.png file then file must be in png format, then the image will not rotate anymore after resize.

Please see the following code:

```
var image = Image.FromStream(formFile.OpenReadStream());
using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fulPath))
{

    TempData.Keep();
    var resized = new Bitmap(image, new Size(160,160));
    var imageStream = new MemoryStream();
    resized.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Png); // <-you must change here for the png or any other file extension here, like your file name is abc.png then the file formate must be png. 


    formFile.CopyTo(fs);

    fs.Flush();
    successmsg = "1";
    return Json(successmsg);
```