# iPhone Photo Orientation Issue with blueimp file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

We are using the blueimp jQuery file upload library and are encountering an issue uploading photos.

When using the software via an iPhone/Safari browser and selecting a photo from the iPhone Photo Library that has a vertical orientation, the software seems to rotate it to a horizontal orientation after upload. The preview seems to work fine, but the final upload is rotated.

You can see this behavior by using the [demo page](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) via an iPhone.

Are there any known fixes or workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I think its not a problem with the blueimp file upload.  There is exif data in the photo that holds the orientation values.  You can modify and rotate the image before you save to the server.

I found this StackOverflow question helpful:
[MVC Get Image Orientation and convert File correct Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation/38459903#38459903)