# Wrong image width and height when read it with C#

Tags: c#, image, height, width

I've got a strange problem. There is an [image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtYIAKM7hRlOgak4oN5_nMNZVvwP6w?e=80a5SS). Unfortunately it's too big to show it in question. But you can download it. If you can't do it from OneDrive [this](https://dropmefiles.com/mkXVu) is another way.

This image seems to be ordinary, but it's not.

When we open properties we will see this:

[image: Image properties in Windows]

We need to keep in mind dimensions of this picture: **Width** is 3000px and **Height** is 4000px. It looks correct because image is portret.

Then lets try to read it with C#:

```
private static void TestImage()
{
    using (FileStream file1 = new FileStream("DSC_2446.JPG", FileMode.Open))
    {                
        Console.WriteLine("DSC_2446.JPG :");
        using (var img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" Width = {img1.Width}");
            Console.WriteLine($" Height = {img1.Height}");
        } 
    }                

    Console.Read();
}
```

And in results we see some magic!!!

[image: Magic results]

So I've got completely wrong values. Values are switched between properties.
Does someone know why it can happens and how to detect/fix this behavior?

Comment: Does it look right if you display it in your app?

Comment: That's the reason I've created this question. It looks wrong. Because it's width and height are changed it looks flattened

Comment: I can't download your image it need to login

Comment: @MichaelMao New link added

Comment: The orientation has to do with the metadata connected with the Image. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation/23400751#23400751

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `EXIF` version. You can use this site to get the real data https://exif.tools/meta/Exif-Version/0231 and you will see

[image]

Also according to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation/23400751#23400751) you can get your image's orientation by

```
var orientation = (int)img1.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
//orientation = 6
```

the value `6` means rotate 90 degrees.

There is the reference of the value 6. https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html

[image]